# How to fix Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have question, Why does I encounter this error on my response, I have module where I need to upload multiple using Ajax and php as backend.

> **Warning**:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in **C:\xampp\htdocs\PSMID\Function\mediaAddFunction.php** on line **17**
>   9
>   **Warning**:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in **C:\xampp\htdocs\PSMID\Function\mediaAddFunction.php** on line **17**

I will share to you guys my sample code that I already made.

**Front End:**

```
var storeFile =[];

    $('#media_file').on('change',function(e){
        var files = e.target.files;

        $.each(files, function(i, file) {

            storeFile.push(file);

        })
    })

    $('.news_media_button').on('click',function(){      

        const media_pages = $('#media_pages').val();
        const media_title = $('#media_title').val();
        //const media_content = $('#media_content').val();
        const ck_editor_content =  CKEDITOR.instances['media_content'].getData();
        const media_link = $('#media_link').val();
        const media_file = $('#media_file').prop('files')[0];
        const hidden_auth_user = $('#hidden_auth_user').val();



        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('media_pages',media_pages);
        data.append('media_title',media_title);
        data.append('media_content',ck_editor_content);
        data.append('media_link',media_link);
        data.append('files',storeFile[0]);
        data.append('hidden_auth_user',hidden_auth_user);

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure to save this data?',
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#008B74',
            confirmButtonText: 'Okay'
            }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'./Function/mediaAddFunction.php',
                    data:data,
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType:'JSON',
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success:function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        //  Swal.fire(
                        //     'Success!',
                        //     'Data Saved.',
                        //     'success'
                        // )
                        // if(response.status == 'Success') {
                        //     location.reload();
                        // }
                    },
                    error:function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
               });

            }
        })

    });
```

**Back End:**

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["files"]["name"]);$i++)
    {
        echo $_FILES["files"]["name"][$i];
    }
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:white">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <input type="hidden" value="" id="hidden_auth_user" name="">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                    <h2 class="col-md-10">News Media</h2>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary news_media_button col-md-2 form-control" id="custom_button">Save Data</button>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label style="font-weight: 500; font-size:14px;">Choose Media Page</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="media_pages">
                                <option value="announcement">Announcement</option>
                                <option value="news_online">News Online</option>
                                <option value="info_graphics">Info Graphics</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label style="font-weight: 500; font-size:14px;">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" name="media_title" id="media_title" placeholder="Title" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label style="font-weight: 500; font-size:14px;">File Upload</label>
                            <div class="custom-file">   
                                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple placeholder="Title" id="media_file" value="" class="custom-file-input form-control">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile04"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label style="font-weight: 500; font-size:14px;">File Link</label>
                            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Link" id="media_link"  value="" class=" form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label style="font-weight: 500; font-size:14px;">Content</label>
                            <textarea cols="12" name="content_article" class="form-control" id="media_content"></textarea>
                            <script>
                                CKEDITOR.replace('content_article');
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code is JQuery + PHP... let's me know how implemented html side for you...

Comment: I suspect you are missing something very important

Comment: You miss the html part... so the $_FILES gives this warning

Comment: @Alessandro what is the missing?

Comment: Miss the HTML part

Comment: If you test my file test.php will work without problems

Comment: You need the MarkUp: `<input type="file" id="files1" name="files[]" size="35">`...

Comment: Otherwise php cannot handle your data

Comment: You need HTML + PHP + JQuery

Comment: okay i will add my html to better understand well

Comment: You miss in the html `<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and `</form>`

Comment: <input> require <form>

Comment: <input type="submit"... where is?

Comment: You miss in your html

Comment: Can I give a suggestion? 1st) try HTML + PHP only. 2nd) when all works add Javascript to complete your project... you lack a verifiable basic model...

Comment: Try to fix your errors...

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @Alessandro sorry i'm off today, maybe tommorow i gonna fix this. i give you update

Comment: Please fix your errors and then talk back to them calmly, it is useless to ask questions if you do not fix the errors that are reported to you ...

Comment: See my updated answer...

Comment: I finally solved your issue...

Answer (score -1):

### Solved your issue:

You have posted your php code exactly like below:

**Back End:**

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["files"]["name"]);$i++)
{
    echo $_FILES["files"]["name"][$i];
}
```

Using your code I have:

> Notice: Undefined index: files in D:\Web\test\files\files-2.php on
>   line 6
>
> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
>   implements Countable in D:\Web\test\files\files-2.php on line 6

To fix your code you have to change your **Back End** with:

```
if (isset($_FILES["files"]["name"])) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["files"]["name"]); $i++) {
    echo $_FILES["files"]["name"][$i];
  }
}
```

This will solve your issue... the magic code is:

```
if (isset($_FILES["files"]["name"])) {
  ...
}
```

Just tested my `files-1.php` file and there is no warning or error, it works fine on real servers with `PHP/7.3.6 (64it)` and `PHP/7.2.17 (64bit)`... also tested on my localhost with same PHP versions...

`files-1.php:`

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<label for="files1">File:</label>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="files1" name="files[]" size="35"><br>
<label for="files2">File:</label>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="files2" name="files[]" size="35"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['files']['name'])) {
  for ($index = 0; $index < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $index++) {
    if ($_FILES['files']['name'][$index] != "") {
      echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$index];
    }
  }
}
?>
```

This my example below (`files-2.php`) has a very little change according to your example, and here I have no warning or error... working on `PHP/7.3.6` and `PHP/7.2.17` on real servers... also tested on my localhost with same PHP versions...

`files-2.php:`

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<label for="files">File:</label>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" size="35" multiple><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['files']['name'])) {
  for ($index = 0; $index < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $index++) {
    if ($_FILES['files']['name'][$index] != "") {
      echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$index];
    }
  }
}
?>
```

[image: test1]
[image: test2]

Source html generated on fly by PHP:

```
<form action="/files/files-2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<label for="files">File:</label>&nbsp;<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" size="35" multiple><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
test.zip
```

As you can see there is no error or warning...

Online testing:

https://3v4l.org/tqgUp

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e0a5326fc2508e1ca4db90051061b4584b86eae

Hope this helps.

Comment: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

Comment: Try with my html

Comment: Your issue sounds like there is no file in $_FILES to count

Comment: I think you're wrong to write something ... try my test file in full

Comment: I respect the amount of effort you've put in here - but this fundamentally changes the premise that OP is trying to use ajax to get this done. Your solution is going to require a page reload. I think OP would learn more if you pointed out any errors that exist in their JavaScript or HTML.

Comment: is a PHP warning... no javascript edit can solve this... IMHO

Comment: In my opinion, every time you access a variable or an array, you must first check if it is set ... this way of looking at me leads me to write code that is free of warnings...

Comment: DevGe asked: _How to fix Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable_. This can be solved server side only IMHO...